# Inserting data via Python into an SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite, input, insert

I'm trying to solve this exercise, and I have no clue why my SQLite DB won't update. Here is what I tried. Any ideas would be much appreciated:

Also, I forgot how to keep the program running, I mean to keep showing the user the options he has :(

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Books")

cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   title TEXT,
   year INT);
""")

user_input = input ("Dear User, you have the following two options, two and only two (case sensitive): \n\t 1. INSERT \n\t 2. SHOW BOOKS \nPlease insert your comamnd here: <<< ")      

if user_input == "1. INSERT":
   
   book_id = input("Book id: ")
   book_title = input("Book title: ")
   book_year = input ("Book year of publication: ")

   cursor.execute
   (""" INSERT INTO Books (id, title, year) VALUES (?,?,?)  
      """, (book_id, book_title, book_year))

   conn.commit()

   print("Book inserted succesfully!")
  

elif user_input == "2. SHOW BOOKS":
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Books;")
   all_results = cursor.fetchall()
   print(all_results)
  

else:
   print("Not a valid command. Try again! It's all case sensitive in Python, u know...")

if (conn):
   conn.close()
```

Comment: well a loop of some sort will keep the program going

Comment: Ok, I see. I will try implementing a loop. But any ideas regarding why the DB won't update with the input values?

Comment: nothing sticks out, though i would give `Books` a file extension like `Books.sqlite`

Comment: Your're right. But still no joy. The DB simply won't update. I get no errors.

Comment: how are you checking that it's updating

Comment: Well, inserting the values with the input() method. Then opening the DB with SQLite.

Comment: have you tried connecting and inserting data just in the python console or somethign?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this part here: book_id, book_title, book_year in  cursor.execute
   (""" INSERT INTO Books (id, title, year) VALUES (?,?,?)  
      """, book_id, book_title, book_year) should have been a tuple, therefore within (), right_

Comment: Did you check that the table exists?